# How to write to yaml file in human readable format?

Tags: python, file, serialization, yaml, pickle

**I have some data types I need to write:**

a. A list of numpy arrays, e.g. `[ndarray, ndarray, ndarray]` of different sizes.

b. Any arbitrary numpy array, e.g. `np.zeros((5,6)), np.randn((76,2))` and so on.

c. Any other future datatype that hasn't occurred to me yet.

**Requirements:**

1. I need a single function to be able to save all those data types, with no specific handling, and with future compatibility for type c stated above.
2. I also need the output file dump in human readable format.

So far, I was only able to achieve requirement 1 with either YAML or pickle, both of which with binary files, i.e. not human readable.

```
@staticmethod
def _read_with_yaml(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as stream:
        return yaml.load(stream)

@staticmethod
def _write_with_yaml(path, obj):
    with io.open(path, 'w+', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        yaml.dump(obj, outfile, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

This example code outputs non-human-readable files, but works for the data types I have.

**Is there a way to achieve both requirements?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your requirements cannot be satisfied.

You already have one function `yaml.dump()` that saves all those data types. As you noticed it doesn't do so in a very readable way for numpy data structures. This is caused by numpy not having dumping routines for their special data structure, instead falling back to the, not-so-readable, default `!python....` tagged dump of the datastructure. Now you (or the YAML or Numpy package maintainers) can provide, special routines for those objects that dump in a more readable format, so that could be covered. You can **make** the representer in your YAML library more intelligent and get more readable output for Numpy datastructures without touching Numpy classes.

But you want this for all future datatypes, and IMO a variation of Gödel's theorem applies: even if the YAML library is extended so that it covers all known cases and dumps them in a readable way, there will always be new datastructures, especially in C based extensions (like Numpy), that cannot be represented in a readable way without extra work.

So because of your

> Any other future unknown datatype that hasn't occurred to me yet.

premise, this is not just a lot of difficult work, but impossible.

Comment: Are you sure about the strict impossibility? In the end, any data structure would be comprised of other data structures, that, recursively, in the end would be some primitives. I assumed some library implemented that in some tree format, but why would it be impossible?

Comment: Also, what about without the "any future" requirement? Is there some library that handles the other use cases internally?

Comment: There is nothing in ruamel.yaml nor in PyYAML (and I don't think NumPy works with the syck library). In principle a third party library could provide better readable representations, but I don't think any library does. I once looked at doing that for ruamel.yaml, but I would have had to dig in too deeply and I am not a NumPy user, so the motivation for that is low.. You should be able monkeypatch those NumPy classes that you are using. If you need help with that (for `ruamel.yaml`) post another question with the full program that dumps, what the output looks like, and what output you want